# Post array nodejs/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, express

i am trying to use post to add a new array with objects to my mongoDB database. The first objects in the array works fine but the NESTED array remains empty. Tried to add .results.answer_option[0] but with no luck. Iam using postman for testing CRUD.

First post on this forum, sorry if its a mess.

**solved it by incrementing the objects:**

```
     {
            answer_text: req.body.results[0].answer_option[0].answer_text,
            is_correct: req.body.results[0].answer_option[0].is_correct,
          },
          {
            answer_text: req.body.results[0].answer_option[1].answer_text,
            is_correct: req.body.results[0].answer_option[1].is_correct,
          },
.....
```

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const movie = new Movie({
    results: [
      {
        category: req.body.results[0].category,
        difficulty: req.body.results[0].difficulty,
        question_text: req.body.results[0].question_text,
        answer_option: [
          {
            answer_text: req.body.answer_option[0].answer_text,
            is_correct: req.body.answer_option[0].is_correct,
          },
          {
            answer_text: req.body.answer_option[0].answer_text,
            is_correct: req.body.answer_option[0].is_correct,
          },
          {
            answer_text: req.body.answer_option[0].answer_text,
            is_correct: req.body.answer_option[0].is_correct,
          },
          {
            answer_text: req.body.answer_option[0].answer_text,
            is_correct: req.body.answer_option[0].is_correct,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  });
```

My postman POST:

```
        
       { "results": [
            {
                "category": "Movies",
                "difficulty": "medium",
                "question_text": "dadasd man and Batman fighting?",
                "answer_option": [
                    {
                        "answer_text": "correct",
                        "is_correct": true
                    },
                    {
                        "answer_text": "test",
                        "is_correct": false
                    },
                    {
                        "answer_text": "test",
                        "is_correct": false
                    },
                    {
                        "answer_text": "test",
                        "is_correct": false
                    }
                ]
            }
            ]
       }
```

movieschema

```
const MovieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
 results: [
   {
     category: String,
     difficulty: String,
     _id: String,
     question_text: {
       type: String,
       required: true,
     },
     answer_option: [
       {
         _id: String,
         answer_text: String,
         is_correct: Boolean,
       },
       {
         _id: String,
         answer_text: String,
         is_correct: Boolean,
       },
       {
         _id: String,
         answer_text: String,
         is_correct: Boolean,
       },
       {
         _id: String,
         answer_text: String,
         is_correct: Boolean,
       },
     ],
   },
 ],
});
```

Comment: I still can't get it.... can add more code. Where is the second array ?

Comment: Sry, I meant the nested array, "answer_option" (:

Comment: Can you post your `Movie` schema? Did you set the `express.urlencoded` middleware?